# Does turning off facial recognition remove (or prevent the creation of) facial templates

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy, facial-recognition

As I understand, facebook's facial recognition creates a facial template for each user based on their photos. Does disabling facial recognition suggestions either delete existing templates or prevent templates from being created? Turning off suggestions does not seem to imply disabling their collection of information.

Also, does facebook only associate facial templates after they have been manually tagged? What if someone else tags another person in their photo (not the second persons). Does that require the second person's permission?

Comment: You should state what country you are in. In the US for example, there is no way for a user to opt out of facial recognition data collection and template creation - Facebook will hide the evidence of it if you turn off suggestions, but they will continue to process images of you uploaded by you and others. This may be a legal question, requiring interpretation of Facebook's Data Policy and Terms in your jurisdiction, in the context of applicable law..

Comment: This would be in the United States. Found this link, which some might consider an answer, but I'd like to know if there are additional sources: https://gizmodo.com/facebooks-new-face-recognition-features-what-we-do-an-1823359911. It states: "You only have a template if you have tag suggestions or face recognition enabled. If you decide to turn off tag suggestions or the new face recognition features, Facebook says the templates are deleted... Users can also opt out of them at any time (using the processes described above) and their templates will be deleted, according to Facebook."

Comment: The flaw in that description is that various users upload photos. Turning off features on your profile can't possibly stop Facebook from creating templates on photos uploaded to another profile. There's a bit of playing telephone going on when we read an article that's written based on the writer talking to an unnamed company rep, and practices are subject to change at any time without notice, so all we really have to go on are the Data Policy and Terms of Use (neither of which address the topic).